# Prevent the background color change on click of cell

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have set the attribute selectable: "multiple cell" of the kendo ui grid.

What actually happens is when I click any cell the cell background color changes to some different color.

I don't want to change the background color on click and want to keep the default color as it is when I click the cell or any where in the row. I am using default CSS and not done any changes in it.

How to do this.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could address this issue by modifying Kendo colour template (http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html) or just overriding following css:

```
.k-grid .k-edit-cell .k-input{
     background-color: pink;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added the above code in kendo.default.css. But when I clicked the row or cell even then the row has background color as orange means the default value set from somewhere. Not sure from where this color is set and how to change it.

Comment: You should not be adding style into Kendo style file. Added on the top of your page into <style> tag or into one of yours css files. Then see if the style you have added is picked up. Chrome  > right click the cell > inspect element > search for style coming from your css file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the above code in my css file but that didn't help me. May be I would have done something wrong or incorrect.

Comment: I was doing it bit wrong. I added your above code in my file and it is working. Thanks.